# shell scripting, if is executed no matter what

Tags: sh

why in this script

```
#!/bin/sh

if [ $1='all' ];
then
    echo $1
    echo "all"
fi
```

all is printed no matter what???

For example I do:  `./thescript.sh`  and I got *clearly* that $1 is empty. But still all is printed. Why? And how can I print "all" when all is passed

Comment: Just a heads up... you might prefer to use `#!/usr/bin/env sh` instead of `#!/bin/sh`. See [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/29620/495409) for more information on the differences

Answer (score 1):

[shellcheck](https://www.shellcheck.net/) has the solution:

> SC2077: You need spaces around the comparison operator.

Change to

```sh
if [ $1 = 'all' ];
```

Without the spaces, the thing between the `[` and `]`is treated as one expression, and `man [` says

> "STRING equivalent to -n STRING

so any non-empty string is considered `true`. (i.e., `if [ "" ];` would be `false`.)

That said, you better specify which shell you want in the shebang. On some systems `/bin/sh` may be `bash`, on others `/bin/dash`, or something else. Pick your shell and avoid any problems from bad assumptions on which shell you actually get.

Comment: If I do that I got `[: =: unexpected operator`

Comment: What shell are you actually using? `ls -l /bin/sh` or `sh --version` What argument are you passing? Nothing? Then `$1` is empty and the whole term is invalid. Try quoting `$1`: `if [ "$1" = 'all' ];` ... another problem shellcheck would have pointed out.

Comment: I just realize. The shell I am using to try this seems to be dash. But the one I am going to use to present this is bash! ohhhh mine...

Answer (score 1):

Put double-quotes around the variable:

```
   #!/bin/sh

   if [ "$1" == "all" ];
   then
       echo $1
       echo "all"
   fi
```

Comment: More importantly, separate the `=` (*not* `==`) from the two strings to compare.

Comment: (`[ $1 = all ]` *can* work as intended as long as `$1` is not empty or unset; `"$1"=all` would never work as intended.)

Comment: And when the $1 is empty (like the example in this question), the error message is '[: =: unary operator expected'. Putting quotes around "$1" will not produce this error when $1 is empty.